# GDIPlus.dll Access violation error

Tags: delphi, gdi+, delphi-2006

I am getting an access violation error stating "Access Violation at address 4EC842CD in module gdiplus.dll".
Language Used : - Delphi 10, Borland Studio 2006
Environment: - Windows XP
I am having an application in which I am using File Open dialog in Delphi which facilitates users to open some type of files from any location of their system. By default it is showing a list of files of that type from a default path.
Now when ever I click on the Open button in the application it shows File open dialog and facilitates the user to open file of that particular type from any location of their system but it is giving an error stating
"Access Violation at address 4EC842CD in module gdiplus.dll".
It is a random error not coming on every PC.

Answer (score 1):

Does this look like the problem : [microsoft kb 901026](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;901026&x=20&y=13) ?
Look for a corrupt font on you system maybe ...

Comment: Ni its not that problem. I have installed the patch from the above url but it is not working.